# Qt ERROR: Signal QQmlEngine::quit() emitted, but no receivers connected to handle it

Tags: python, python-3.x, qml, pyside2

i wrote an example PySide2/QML code but i can't make it to quit the program.

PySide2 Code:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView

QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

view = QQuickView(QUrl('view.qml'))
view.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

QML Code:

```
import QtQuick 2.3
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4

Rectangle {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    color: "green"

    Button {
        text: "Hello World"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        onClicked: Qt.quit()
    }
}
```

running with code in command prompt gives me an error when i click the button:

```
Signal QQmlEngine::quit() emitted, but no receivers connected to handle it.
```

searching the web i realized others had similar issues because of Qt's new syntax. but it's all in C++ and i don't understand it.

does anyone know how to resolve this issue in Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#quit-method) notes:

> **quit()**
>
> This function causes the [QQmlEngine::quit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#quit) signal to be emitted.
>   Within the [Prototyping with qmlscene](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-qmlscene.html), this causes the launcher
>   application to exit; to quit a C++ application when this method is
>   called, connect the [QQmlEngine::quit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#quit) signal to the
>   [QCoreApplication::quit()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) slot.

Clearly point out that you have to connect the QQmlEngine::quit() of QQuickView to QCoreApplication::quit():

```py
import os
import sys

from PySide2.QtCore import QCoreApplication, Qt, QUrl
from PySide2.QtGui import QGuiApplication
from PySide2.QtQuick import QQuickView

if __name__ == "__main__":
    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_EnableHighDpiScaling)
    app = QGuiApplication(sys.argv)

    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    filename = os.path.join(current_dir, "view.qml")
    view = QQuickView(QUrl.fromLocalFile(filename))
    view.engine().quit.connect(QCoreApplication.quit)  # <---
    view.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```